# Javascript immediately invoked function expression "this"

Tags: javascript

This seems to correctly return the correct value of 1:

```
let test = function() {
  let test = 1;
  function getTest() {
    return test;
  }
  return {getTest};
}();

console.log(test.getTest());
```

But this does not:

```
let test = function() {
  this.test = 1;
  function getTest() {
    return this.test;
  }
  return {getTest};
}();

console.log(test.getTest());
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what exactly you were trying to achieve with your code. An IIFE should not be mixed up with an object instantiation which I have demonstrated below. In this context the `this` works as expected:

```js
const test=new function() { // object instantiation 
  this.test = 1; // this defines the property test
  this.getTest=function(){
    return this.test; // this references the same property 
  }
};
// test.test=123; // you can manipulate the property test here
console.log(test.getTest());
```

Or, in form of a simple object assignment:

```js
const test={ // object assignment
  test: 1,                       // defines the property `test`
  getTest(){ return this.test; } // the `this` references the `test` property 
};

console.log(test.getTest());
```

Answer (score -1):

Because of the scope of `this`.

```js
let test = function() {
  this.test = 1; // this refers to the scope of the 1st level function 
  function getTest() {
    return this.test; // this refers to the getTest function, and is undefined
  }
  return {getTest};
}();

console.log(test.getTest());
```

Just to make the point of the behavior of `this` you could use an arrow function, which captures the encompassing scope, including `this`

```js
let test = function() {
  this.test = 1;
  const getTest = ()=> this.test; // still points to upper function
  return {getTest};
}();

console.log(test.getTest());
```

But note that this a bad practice in this case because you keep in memory a reference to a function after it has reach end of scope. You shouldn't return any reference to `this` from a this kind of immediately invoked function, it creates a memory leak.

So a better thing to do would be to define the function and the `test` value on the returned object, with `this` being a reference to this object an not of a closure's scope object that doesn't exist any more

```js
let test = function() {
  return {
    test: 1,
    getTest() {
      return this.test;
    },
  }
}();

console.log(test.getTest());
```